# how to get throughput of samples while running jmeter in non-GUI mode?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

How to get the throughput of the samples while running jmeter in non-GUI mode?

In cmd only Avg,Min,Max,Err,Time elapsed is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Actually you have the throughput when you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui):

   [image]
2. You can get a little bit more information if you run your JMeter test using Taurus tool as the wrapper:

   [image]

   or much more information if you run Taurus with `-report` command-line argument, it will kick off your default browser and bring up real-time results in a fancy web interface:

   [image]

   Check out [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) article for more details if needed
3. And last but not the least you can add a [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) and point it to your [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/products/influxdb-overview/) installation, once done you will be able to use [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to view current test execution results in the real time:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you for the information.From the image reference1, throughput is increasing for 20 hits. For my application, I had run 75 user hits- throughput value analysis is little bit confusing.can you please me to extrapolate the data

Comment: 7.9/s Avg:  3303 Min:     0 Max: 11525 Err:     0 (0.00%)
6.9/s Avg:  2985 Min:     0 Max:  9257 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 75 Started: 75 Finished: 0
7.3/s Avg:  3655 Min:   125 Max:  8302 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 53 Started: 75 Finished: 22
7.8/s Avg:  3345 Min:     0 Max: 11525 Err:     0 (0.00%)
4.8/s Avg:  2380 Min:   135 Max:  5339 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 75 Finished: 75
7.7/s Avg:  3334 Min:     0 Max: 11525 Err:     0 (0.00%)

Answer (score 0):

by default if you're running your JMX file using cmd you will throughput in the cmd itself or if you want to see some more information you can use Taurus tool as well check this for more https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html